# ipython pyspark 'range' object has no attribute 'defaultParallelism'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I have setup pyspark for ipython, and from within ipython, I can successfully import pyspark.

I am using ipython in anaconda, python 3.4. And here is an snapshot of the prolem.

[image]

Note that, this command works in pyspark

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015 15:33:21)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> sc.parallelize(range(10), 3)
ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:423
>>> 
>>> irdd = sc.parallelize(range(10), 3)
>>> irdd.collect()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                                  
>>> irdd.glom().collect()
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

I have configured it as follows

```
export SPARK_HOME=$HOME/apps/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling the `parallelize` method on the `SparkContext` class rather than an instance of `SparkContext`:

In your IPython notebook code, the import statement

```
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
```

is just giving the name `sc` to the SparkContext class, not creating a new SparkContext.

See the ["Initializing Spark"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#initializing-spark) section in the Spark programming guide for instructions on creating a SparkContext instance. For example, to emulate the local context which is created in `spark-shell`, try

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app-name-of-your-choice").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
# Your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Josh's answer: 
I was having the same problem and indeed importing the SparkContext as sc or just creating sc = SparkContext is not the same as saying sc = SparkContext().

However, I was being told that I had multiple SparkContexts running and it hated me.

The solution for me was to use:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("miniProject").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
```

Then when I ran:

```
sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],4).map(lambda x: x**2).sum()
```

I got the expected answer of 385. 
So, the key is the getOrCreate method as it lets you find the existing context and use it.